# After having installed APC Object Cache Backend transients stopped working

Tags: cache, transient, apc

My understanding is that once you enable the persistent object cache, your transients are no longer stored in `wp_options` but in the cache.

Once I installed Mark Jaquith's APC Object Cache Backend, calls to `get_transient( $key )` no longer return the transient in question.

Where should I look next?

EDIT: One very important piece of evidence is that AS SOON as I renamed the `object-cache.php` file, everything started working again.

Comment: Are you sure the transient has been set?

Comment: Hi Mark. Sure? Not 100%. I have yet to pull this all out into a (non-live) sandbox where I can do more testing. All I know is that I was setting transients and reading them in fine, then I installed APC and your Object Cache Backend, and started returning false on ALL the transients I was setting.

Comment: Now, I should also say, that once I installed the Object Cache Backend, some of my SQL query data was being cached. As in, I'd go into Admin > Edit User, change the email address, hit Update, see that the email address was changed, and then on the front end, view the user's page and the old email address was there, persisting a few minutes. Very odd. I only mention this because it may be I was setting an incorrect code on the transient, with the problem being on WRITE rather than on READ.

Comment: @MarkJaquith if you say you've tested the whole transients thing and it works great, then I'm sure the problem is somewhere else (in my code or business logic), possibly only tangentially related to your APC OCB. Unless SQL cacheing is the culprit. Maybe there's a tweak I should make to APC config?

Comment: Tom, Just to let you know, I am having the same problem. Mark recently showed me how to test it and transients are definitely not working with APC OCB. I'm thinking about hacking a fix myself until Mark figures out a proper fix. -Devin

Comment: Thanks @meeble for the update. It's a little hard for me to be as proactive as I'd like to be because it's on a production server where we have had to turn off the cache as a result, and I'm leery to turn it back on. If there is a fix, please come back and post it here so I can close out this thread!

Comment: What version of APC are you all using?

Comment: APC Version 3.1.9; PHP Version 5.3.5